# Water Heater Venting

Tags: water-heater

I'm looking to purchase a house. They had a pre-inspection that flagged the water heater venting as defective because it didn't rise high enough. The owner followed up with the installer (perhaps biased?) who claimed that the venting didn't need to go up 12 inches first (because of the model). They said based on the model, which I believe is an ao smith proline water heater gcrl-40, they said that only an upward slope of 1/4 inch per linear foot was required, which it has. I'm skeptical that it meets that requirement based on the picture and seeing it in person. What do you think? Can the vent be linear as long as it's not so for more than one foot? Or does ever part need to be sloped up. Any input would be appreciated.

For context, I *believe* that once it enters the wall it goes up the chimney.

[image]

Edits based on comments so far.

I have placed a level on it, and it is level, perhaps slightly upward. But doesn't seem to slope downward. I do believe this goes directly into the chimney, which is in the middle of the house. This house is in Wisconsin, so there are cold winters. How would I be able to tell if  there is enough draft to reliably pull the exhaust? Would simple CO detectors be able to detect if there was a poor draft? I was curious if the 1/4 inch sloping up per foot had to be continuous or if as long as more than 1 entire foot wasn't horizontal, it wouldn't be an issue.

For additional context, I did contact local installers of ao smith products, and the 3 I heard back from all didn't believe the installation would be an issue (though I wasn't able to get more context on why they believe that to be true).

Comment: That's AO Smith, the logo is confusing if you are not familiar with the brand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your water heater looks almost identical to mine - different brand but also called "ProLine". Then again, all gas tank water heaters are going to look pretty much the same.

In any case, the manual at https://www.hotwater.com/lit/im/res_gas/100263112.pdf page 11 says:

> **Vent Installation**
> To improve the fl ow of exhaust gases, we recommend that a minimum of 12 inches of vertical vent pipe be installed on the draft hood prior to any elbow. A portion of the vent pipe (up to 75% of the total vertical height) can be horizontal, but the termination on must be vertical. For the horizontal section, install without dips or sags with an upward slope of at least ¼ inch per foot.

Strictly speaking, that means the "12 inches" minimum is not absolutely required, just a *recommendation*. In defense of the installer, they were likely, as is almost always the case, reusing existing venting and moving it up would require breaking into the wall. It is quite possible that the previous tank was a little shorter and had 12" of vertical vent pipe before the horizontal pipe. There *might* be a code requirement for the 12" minimum, but I don't know.

However, the manual makes no "recommend" with reference to the horizontal section minimum slope of 1/4" per foot. It looks to me like it is sloping downward, not upward. Put a level on it to see for sure, as it may just be the camera angle and shadows. If it indeed is not sloping up, then that would likely violate the rules because it violates installation instructions.

As to whether this is truly a problem and not just technical, it could be a real problem. There are a few concerns:

- Is there enough draft to pull the exhaust, including CO (very dangerous) and CO2 (less dangerous but not good for you), reliably up and out?

A CO detector is a good idea. But while that will give you warning of a CO problem, CO is actually a problem primarily when there is incomplete combustion - i.e., when something isn't working properly. When everything is working 100% properly, you will get a *lot* of CO2, so sufficient draft matters even without a CO problem.

- Do you have significant risk of condensation settling in the horizontal section of the pipe?

This is, I suspect, the meaning of the 1/4" slope. 1/4" slope over several feet is not enough to affect the draft. But you don't want any low spots to collect condensate. Ideally all the water vapor should go up the chimney. But any that doesn't should come all the way back down and not sit in the pipe - a consistent upward slope is key to making that happen.

Comment: Yes, "recommend" is not a requirement. UL approves these instructions as part of approving the equipment (and there's evidence that UL basically writes instructions).  In order for that installation to be wrong, we must presume that UL made a flub and wrote 'recommend' when they meant to write 'required'. Makes no sense. UL knows all the words that rhyme with 'mandatory' and love to say them!

Comment: Absolutely agree that the critical question is whether this does in fact draw well enough, in all kinds of weather. Carbon monoxide poisoning is no joke. Is also add that what you really want to know may not be the manufacturer's advice, but what local building code requires.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I disagree. I think "recommend" was deliberate to allow for legitimate exceptions. Arguably if this turned to a 45-degree upslope within 6" there wouldn't be much concern. As I noted, in this replacement situation, 12" vertical first would have been an expensive fix (break into the wall). That being said, it could have been installed in a way that at *minimum* would get upslope instead of so nearly horizontal.

Comment: @keshlam But all I can answer is the manufacturer's advice. I can't guess at the local code without knowing the jurisdiction - and then it may be hard to find the info.

Comment: Right. But the original poster is in a perfect position to walk into the local inspector's office and ask.